# Understanding terminology of Mixtures of Gaussians model

Tags: normal-distribution, machine-learning, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I'm following [this](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes/cs229-notes7b.pdf) lecture notes to understand mixture of Gaussian model and EM (Expectation Maximization) algorithm to fit it.

I understand the complete intuition behind this algorithm, which is explained [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808074/what-is-an-intuitive-explanation-of-the-expectation-maximization-technique) But I don't understand the terminology used in the lecture notes to mathematically express this algorithm.

It's written that we want to model the joint distribution of

$$p(x^{(i)}, z^{(i)}) = p(x^{(i)}| z^{(i)}) p(z^{(i)})$$

Here what is the intuitive meaning of $p(x^{(i)}, z^{(i)})$? How they came up with such expression? Here I know what $z^{(i)}$ means. It's one of the $k$ possible Gaussian distributions from which $x^{(i)}$ came from. Correct me here if I'm wrong.

I also don't understand from where the following log likelihood formula came from.

$$l(φ, μ, Σ) = \sum_{i=1}^m \log p(x^{(i)}; φ, μ, Σ)$$

which is equal to

$$\sum_{i=1}^m \log \sum_{z^{(i)}=1}^k p(x^{(i)}|z^{(i)} ; μ,Σ) p(z^{(i)}; φ)$$

Also the other thing which I don't understand is in explanation on EM algorithm, I can't figure out from where the formula for $φj$, $μj$ and $Σj$ is derived.

[image]

How can I derive this Maximization step of EM algorithm?